# Exceptional locus of proper birational morphism from smooth variety to normal variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be a proper birational morphism. Suppose that $X$ is normal and $Y$ is smooth.
Let us write the largest open subset U of X such that $f^{-1}$ can be defined.

I want to show that $\operatorname{codim}(X\backslash U)\geq2$.

I think that I should use Zariski's main theorem but I don't know how to use. Thank you.

Comment: You write that “$Y$ is normal.”  However the title of your post suggests that $Y$ is smooth and $X$ is normal.

Comment: Oh I made a mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: You do not need Zariski's Main Theorem for this.  It follows already from the valuative criterion of properness.